# Trying to run an UPDATE stored procedure in C# but it's not doing anything

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

When I run the stored procedure manually, it works fine.  However, whenever I try to call it with my code below, nothing is updating.  One thing I've noticed is that in my stored procedure, I change the "Modified Date" field to the current time/date and that IS updating; however, none of my other values are.

Here's my method I'm using:

```
public void EditProduct(int productID, string productName, string productNumber, string productColor, string productSubcategory)
    {
        ConfigureDataAccess();
        myCommand = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[UpdateProductInfo]", myConnection);
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", productID);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(productName) ? (object)DBNull.Value : (object)productName);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductNumber", String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(productNumber) ? (object)DBNull.Value : (object)productNumber);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductColor", String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(productColor) ? (object)DBNull.Value : (object)productColor);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductSubcategory", String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(productSubcategory) ? (object)DBNull.Value : (object)productSubcategory);

        try
        {
            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException exception)
            {
                exception.Data.Add("cstring", myConfiguration);
                throw;
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                ex.Data.Add("cStatus", myConnection.State);
                throw;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
```

I don't believe `ConfigureDataAccess()` is an issue because other methods are using it and they are running fine.  Is there anything that immediately sticks out?

Edit:  Here's my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateProductInfo]

@ProductID as int,
@ProductName as varchar(50),
@ProductNumber as varchar(25),
@ProductColor as varchar(15),
@ProductSubcategory as varchar(50)

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE P
SET P.Name = @ProductName, P.ProductNumber = @ProductNumber, P.Color = @ProductColor, P.ModifiedDate = GetDate(), 
P.ProductSubcategoryID = (SELECT PS.ProductSubcategoryID FROM Production.ProductSubcategory PS WHERE PS.Name = @ProductSubcategory)
FROM Production.Product as P
LEFT OUTER JOIN  Production.ProductSubcategory as PS ON P.ProductSubcategoryID = PS.ProductSubcategoryID
WHERE P.ProductID = @ProductID
END
```

Here's my `ConfigureDataAccess()` method:

```
    private string myConfiguration;
    private SqlConnection myConnection;
    private SqlCommand myCommand;
    private SqlDataReader myReader;
    private List<Product> myProducts;

    public void ConfigureDataAccess()
    {
        myConfiguration = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnection"].ConnectionString;
        myConnection = new SqlConnection(myConfiguration);
        myReader = null;
        myProducts = new List<Product>();
    }
```

Comment: Please post your ConfigureDataAccess() method and the stored procedure so people can replicate the issue.

Comment: This is a bit of a guess, but change your commandtext to exec [dbo].[UpdateProductInfo]. May be ADO is putting some stuff in front of the call and you can only get away without exec if it's the first command in the batch. Ingore, just read the date changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.  I needed to include `if (!IsPostBack)` in my `Page_Load` event.  I didn't realize that when I was clicking the "Save" button on my webform that it was posting back and setting my textboxes (on which the parameters in the `EditProduct()` method are getting their values) back to their original values.

Answer (score 0):

I would try removing the LEFT JOIN phrase of the SQL statement.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN  Production.ProductSubcategory as PS ON P.ProductSubcategoryID = PS.ProductSubcategoryID
```

I think the sql will work fine without it.

Comment: Sorry, I initially had a slightly different UPDATE statement in which that LEFT JOIN was necessary.  You're right, I didn't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I don't see the use of the Left outer join. Remove and try. The other thing that may help is stop supressing exception while you are on development. Comment the try catch to see exceptions (if any).